# SQUID : Allowing Specific dst IPs through Cache_Peer and block the rest

Tags: squid

I have a Squid server using a parent Machine(**192.168.1.18**) to access to country A while the Internet connection on Squid(**192.168.1.19**) belongs to country B. I need proxy authenticated users to use the Squid to access specific IPs through A(parent) link and the rest of requests getting blocked or dropped for both local and external requests.

Below is my configuration which is not working as i mentioned above and my mind is stopped working!, Please help and assist:

```
cache_peer 192.168.1.18 parent 10809 0 no-query no-digest
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid_passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Basic Authentication
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow auth_users

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
# acl Safe_ports port 21                # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
# acl Safe_ports port 70                # gopher
# acl Safe_ports port 210               # wais
# acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535        # unregistered ports
# acl Safe_ports port 280               # http-mgmt
# acl Safe_ports port 488               # gss-http
# acl Safe_ports port 591               # filemaker
# acl Safe_ports port 777               # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

acl GOOD dstdomain (Domain1) (Domain2) (Domain3)
acl BAD dst all
never_direct deny BAD
never_direct deny !GOOD
always_direct deny BAD
always_direct deny !GOOD
http_access allow GOOD
http_access deny !GOOD
http_access deny BAD

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

**Thank you!**